# Customized widget not showing up in dashing Dashboard

Tags: widget, dashboard, dashing

I created my own widget but I am unable to view that widget but all the other predefined widgets are showing up in the screen. Whatever widget I install new I am unable too see it in dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old but let me give it a shot.

In such a scenario, you should check the console of your browser to see any possible error messages. It's most likely that there's an error within the execution of your widgets coffee script.